# How to change the contents of the title to two lines

Tags: svg

I know SVG has a `<title>` element. I want to have the title show in multiple lines when the user hovers the mouse over the text. How would I do that?

[image]

```
<text>
    hoverthis
    <title>one <br/> two<title>
</text>
```

Comment: ‘<text>hover <title>this is one <br/> this is two </title> </text>’ But that's no use

Comment: Can you give me an example？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a carriage return.

```html
<svg>
  <rect fill="blue" width="100%" height="100%">
    <title>one 
two</title>
</rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: But I want to user code to add title`s content like

Comment: But I want to user code to add title`s content like‘str+=“”text“; title.append(str); ’how to add a carriage to code?

Comment: ask another question, be sure to provide a clear description, your research so far into it and where you are stuck.

Comment: str+='\n' is sure  to fix